# Chart using json from external url

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api, charts, lightning-connect

Is there a way to have a salesforce native chart use a url that provides JSON as the data for the chart?

I keep reading about lightning connect and OData to connect to an external database, but I'm not trying to do that per se, as I did not need those two things to display data in lightning from the same url

or i guess i could use high charts or another charting library, just wanted to see what the options were for the native

any help on answering this would be massively appreciated